# Firebase Database Rules - Get displayName

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I added Firebase to my website and created a signup form.
When the user clicks the "signup" button it creates a user using "Firebase Authentication", then it updates the user's displayName, and finally adds some data about the user to the database:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function () {

    profile = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    profile.updateProfile({
       displayName: "name-value"
    }).then(function() {

        // Update successful.

        firebase.database().ref("/users/" + profile.uid).set({
            data:{
                country: "country-value",
                city: "city-value"
            }
        });
    });
}).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
});
```

Everything worked fine until I changed the database rules from:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
        }
    }
}
```

To:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "users": {
            ".read": true,
            "$user": {
                ".write": "auth.token.name !== null"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used **auth.token.name** as it is written in the [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#authtoken) to check whether or not the user's displayName exists (I planned to make it check some more things about it later).
Somehow "firebase rules" 'thinks' that **auth.token.name** equals null, even though I set the displayName before. Why is it happening and what can I do to make it work?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you trying using the same user previously created with a name or are you trying to signup a new user?

Comment: The purpose of the page that I've created is signing up a new user, changing the displayName, and finally uploading some data about him to the database.

Comment: @OmerShahar so, sir, did you ever find a fix for this? I have similar rule in my db which is $displayName == auth.token.name but this is never true and i cannot test what auth,.token.name actually have as value because i am sure that user has updated displayName!

Comment: @lowzyyy I tried to check and see what was my solution back then. It looks like I gave up on `displayName` and instead just saved it in the DB. I found it more reliable, and you can still use values from the DB in your security rules. However, I wrote that code more than four years ago, so things might have changed since then.

Comment: @OmerShahar i gave up too. tried solution with uid and it works ($uid==auth.uid as rule). Google firebase software is full of bugs. It's not the first time that something does not work

Answer (score 3):

First, Firestore has replaced Realtime Database and should be used for all projects going forward - more features.

Re Realtime DB rules, it's is best practice to check `uid` variable vs display name. See [Variables](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#variables):

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    "$comment": {
      ".write": "!data.exists() && newData.child('user_id').val() == auth.uid"
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, IIF you implement database security rules using Firebase Authentication, you MUST use `.onAuthStateChanged` to drive your application as your `auth()` variables WILL BE `null` for a second on initial page/app load as this is an asynchronous method. So, don't try and write or read anything on DOM `ready`. You must trigger db conversations within `.onAuthStateChanged` like below:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
        //USER SIGNED IN. WE ARE READY
    }
    else {
        //USER IS NOT SIGNED IN
    }
});
```

Comment: "Firestore has replaced Realtime Database and should be used for all projects going forward - more features." While Firestore is definitely the newest database product from Firebase, this blanket statement is simply not true. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/rtdb-vs-firestore for a good comparison.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, but even after I moved the parts of code (where I updated the displayName and added data to the databse) into .onAuthStateChanged, it still didn't work. Then I tried the same thing with Firestore, as you suggested (allow write: if request.auth.name != null;), but it also didn't work... It still says that the displayName equals to null...

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen What would be a use case for Realtime DB over Firestore besides sharding? The link you shared says _Cloud Firestore is Firebase's new flagship database for mobile app development. It ...  features richer, faster queries and scales better than the Realtime Database._

Comment: Just taking a single quote from that page doesn't do it justice, there's too much information in there to simply copy/paste here (which is why I didn't). And even then, the page is incomplete missing a significant section on presence (see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence). Everyone making the choice should read the page in its entirety and then make their own choice.

Comment: I'll simply have to defer to Lord Puf , I will no longer say Firestore is preferred going forward. Pardon the overreach :-)

Comment: It all depends on your project. If you don't need presence, can do with the slower realtime, want web offline, then I definitely go with Firestore. It's just not a blanket call. I usually say something like "if you're just getting started on this, I'd definitely consider using Firestore".

Comment: @RonRoyston So, as I commented a few days ago, I tried to use `.onAuthStateChanged` (with both Realtime and Firestore) but the rules still 'thought' that `request.auth.name` is null. Do you have another solution that might work? Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: @Programmer use `auth.uid` not `request.auth.name`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and figured out a better solution. Firebase has a feature called [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) that is meant for the use case we have. You want to set some id on a Firebase Anonymous Auth User that is accessible from database security rules.

The high-level of the solution is to make a Cloud Function that uses the admin api to set a custom claim. You can't set custom claims from the client side.

Next, call the cloud function to update the custom claim then use `Auth.auth().currentUser?.getIDTokenResult(forcingRefresh: true,...` in order to retrieve the updated token which includes the custom claim. This step is critical because you need your custom claim to be sent as part of every request moving forward.

If anyone actually reads this I can type up a more detailed implementation example.